# Generate objects dynamically with onclick following

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need a function that creates a div element and an object so I can assign to each div a object to work with it later. The idea behind this is create a visual interface that let you add values to a concrete object depending which box you click.

For example:

[image]

Clicking one box will load the content (in this case is "" (nothing)) to the selects and inputs so I can update them.

The object content

```
{
            "Option1": "",
            "Option2": "",
            "Option3": "",
            "Option4": "",
            "Option5": "",

        }
```

And I'm going to fill the object using selects and inputs.

How can I do this? I have the following that creates a single object filled with the selects and inputs:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.selectVal, input');
        var results = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var element = elements[i];
            var strSel = '';
            if (element.tagName == 'SELECT'){
                strSel = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
            }
            else if (element.tagName == 'INPUT'){
                strSel = element.value;
            }

            results[element.id] = strSel;
            console.log(results)
        }


        strSel = JSON.stringify(results, null, 4);
        var blob = new Blob([strSel], {type: "application/json"});
        var url  = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.download    = "archivo.json";
        a.href        = url;
        a.textContent = "Descargar JSON";

        console.log(strSel);
        document.getElementById('json').innerHTML = strSel;
        document.getElementById('download').appendChild(a);
```

After that, I can create my box:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.className = 'new-box';       
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
```

Now is where I get lost, how do I control that the new object is attached to this box and create new objects every time I click? The closest I get to what I want is:

```
            var boxes= [];
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.className = 'new-box';       
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
            boxes.push(div);
            boxes.push(results);
```

But I don't want to generate the boxes already filled, I want to generate them wit the second argument clean and then after clicking the box fill it.